# ReactJS как подключить модуль fs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, импорт, fs

Я использую create-react-app, мне не удается подключить модуль fs. Подключаю с помощью import fs from 'fs', пытаюсь сделать запись fs.writeFile(....), в результате ошибка ... is not a function

Comment: А что это вы вообще пытаетесь сделать? Писать файл из реакта (который вообще-то выполняется в браузере) это очень странная идея.

Answer (score -3):

Решение: я использовал модуль на клиенте, что естественно он не будет выполняться. Настроил сервер на nodejs - server.js, который обрабатывает мои запросы через fetch с моего приложения react. Т.е теперь запросы идут на сервер и там уже принимаю запрос и обрабатываю и могу выполнить модуль fs

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/479363)

Comment: является ответом на вопрос не глупи

Comment: @Лукас ваша не осведомленность не является ответом на ваш вопрос. Вы пытаетесь взаимодействовать с файловой системой в браузере, о чем может идти речь? Изучите стек технологий который вы используете.

Comment: ну дальше что? Я понял что никак не получится использовать модуль fs на клиенте. Вот и ответ использовать на сервере. Зачем вы ответ губите? Ведь явно найдутся люди с похожей проблемой.